# ArcMap - Definition query with subquery using a date returns wrong result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql

In ArcMap 10.6, I am using the following definition query on a featureClass to get the features that are underway but the results is not what I expected. Data are stored in an Enterprise geodatabase hosted on PostgreSQL.

```
numeroprojet IN (SELECT numeroprojet FROM FeatureClass_P WHERE datedebut <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND datefin >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

It seems that the subquery does not select all the features where `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is between `datedebut` and `datefin`. This happens only in subqueries.

If I add the same query to the definition expression of the featureClass `FeatureClass_P`, like below, the result is correct

```
datedebut <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND datefin >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Here the results from the query above in arcmap. It returns 18 records (those in the red rectangle are missing from the same query in pgadmin)

[image]

If I do the same query on `FeatureClass_P` in pgadmin, I got 14 records (just like the subquery in the first statement)

[image]

It seems that the subquery in the first statement returns the same result than pgadmin, which is 4 record less than a direct definition query in arcmap.

At the moment of this post the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from pgadmin is the following:

[image]

Any idea why there is such difference? The correct results are those from direct definition query in arcmap (18 records)

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the RDBMS in use.

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: It should use the system time on the machine that's running the database.  That's what my postgres database is showing when I select current_timestamp.

Comment: But the result is different if it's a query or a subquery

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you run the query in PGAdmin?

Comment: @TurboGraphxBeige no, I have edited my question with resutls from arcmap vs results from pgadmin with the same query

Comment: Did you try to [create a query layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/working-with-layers/creating-a-query-layer.htm) instead of using a definition expression?

Comment: Something stranger now, the rows count are not the same in arcCatalog than in pgadmin. I have verified the connection file and I am 100% certain that it's the same table in arcCatalog and pgadmin

Comment: @BelowtheRadar, About your last comment, In my experience, a geometry could be considered valid in QGIS and not in ArcMap, using the same PostGIS table. ArcMap is quite picky sometimes... Maybe that may explain the row count between ArcCatalog and PGAdmin?

Comment: What if you try with LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a timestamp with a timezone, LOCALTIMESTAMP returns a timestamp without time zone. Your datetime fields don't have a time zone either.

Comment: @TurboGraphxBeige using LOCALTIMESTAMP did not solve my problem. I don't think the problem is with the timestamp now as some missing features should be returned even if the timezone is incorrect because the debutdate is yesterday. I think the table is somewhat corrupted. I have made a copy in arcCatalog and with this new table, the number of rows and the results of the queries are correct both in arcMap and pgadmin.